# Importar datos de un fichero txt para asignar a variables

Tags: python-3.x

Sigo siendo totalmente novato en esto del lenguaje Python....

Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo un archivo .txt en el que hay 5 columnas con datos numéricos. Quiero que la columna 1 sea la variable a, que la columna 2 sea la variable b, y así hasta la columna 5. Cuando esas variables estén asignadas las utilizaré como parámetros en una función (no sé si estoy empleando la terminología correcta, lo siento). Pongo el script que estoy haciendo (acepto carcajadas....).

```
from obspy.taup import TauPyModel
model = TauPyModel(model="iasp91")

archivo=open('Dat.txt', 'r')
lista=archivo.readlines()
archivo.close

a=columna 1
b=columna 2
c=columna 3
d=columna 4
e=columna 5

arrivals=model.get_pierce_points_geo(a, b, c, d, e, phase_list=('SKS',), resample=False)

arrival = arrivals[0]
#arrival.pierce, arrival.incident_angle

#print(arrivals)
print(arrival.pierce)
#print(arrival.path)
```

Probando valores de las variables (ejemplo: a=12; b=57,23;...etc) el script hace lo que tiene que hacer. El problema es que no se traducirle a Python lo que quiero hacer porque soy muy novato. La idea es la que tengo en el script (sé que así no está bien escrito porque se que columna 1, 2, 3 etc no están definidas, pero sí que es lo que quiero conseguir).

En principio, solo tengo una fila en el .txt porque es de prueba. La idea final es que el .txt tenga 20 filas (por ejemplo) y que el script vaya haciendo bucle para cada una de las filas (se que utilizaré el for pero no como) arrojando los resultados para cada una.

Recuerdo que estoy en nivel ultrabásico. 
Muchas gracias por todo.

Comment: Hola Seismo, es importante que coloque un ejemplo de la linea del txt (csv) para poder reproducir el problema y saber datos esenciales como es el separador que usas entre columnas. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola. El ejemplo es tal cual lo ponía Juanmhs, es decir, para simplificarlo tengo un .txt que tiene una única fila con estos valores separados por comas: 408, 47.6981, 146.9212, 36.882277, -3.068689. Solo separados por comas, no hay ningún espacio. El script hace un print con los valores (siguiendo las ordenes) pero da el error. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que debes definir es el formato del archivo .txt para poder leerlo de forma correcta podria ser como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
```

Luego de eso puedes leer el archivo y cada linea seria un recorrido del bucle y cada columna estaría separada por comas:

```py
archivo = open("prueba.txt", "r")
for linea in archivo.readlines():
    columna= str(linea).split(",")
    print(columna[0])
    print(columna[1])
    print(columna[2])
    print(columna[3])
    print(columna[4])
archivo.close()
```

Con la funcion `split(param)` convertimos una cadena de caracteres en un list de python, donde param seria el caracter que separa la cadena

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. He probado a implementar el código que me dijiste pero sale un error. El error es el siguiente:  File "C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\pierce.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(columna[1])  
IndexError: list index out of range  Me imprime los valores de las teóricas columnas pero solo puedo utilizar la de columna[0]

Comment: Verificastes que el archivo `prueba.txt` tenga los valores en el formato que te indique en la respuesta

Comment: Hola. Tengo un .txt con una sola fila con el ejemplo que tú me diste. Los valores de la fila son: 408, 47.6981, 146.9212, 36.882277, -3.068689. Están con coma pero sin el espacio con el que lo redacto aquí. Imprime los valores pero tras esto da el error. Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Cuando ejecuto el código sucede lo siguiente: `408
47.6981
146.9212
36.882277
-3.068689

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pierce.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(columna[1])
IndexError: list index out of range` Gracias.

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que a lo mejor estás dejando una línea en blanco al final del archivo y cómo es una línea más el programa la lee pero no puede hacer el split

Comment: Problema solucionado. Era exactamente eso. He creado un nuevo .txt asegurándome de que solo ponía los caracteres correctos. Sin embargo, ahora me da otro error referente a la función que estoy intentando utilizar. Desde aquí que me recomendáis, ¿sigo escribiendo en este post el código que tengo y el error que genera o abro uno nuevo?. Muchas gracias.

Comment: También soy nuevo aquí, pero creo que deberías abrir un post nuevo ya que son problemas diferentes